# Jquery generated iframe - no referer for clicks

Tags: jquery, iframe, opera, referer

Here is sample code which is generating iframe on site

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {'pid'   : '2287534092a5acc28854b424e8b77d14'};
    window.onload = function(){var code = document.createElement('script'); code.type = 'text/javascript'; code.async = true; code.src = 'http://site.com/testscript.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(code, s);};
</script>
<div name="site[]" mob_width="100%" mob_height="28" mob_bgcolor="orange" mob_linkcolor="green"></div>
```

Sample site is donmob.com - if you see on the footer there is a green graphic banner - this banner is showing in iframe - so when we click on the banner we must get url address of iframe like referer.
The problem is that Opera Mini is not sending referers for clicks from insde the iframe - please help to get referers for this browser

Answer (score 0):

Opera Mini is usually sending HTTP Referer. Could you test with the [echo system of Opera](http://echo.opera.com/) and update the question with the raw log you get.